# error in HTML files in Android Project - `Self-closing syntax (/>) used on a non-void HTML element`

Tags: android, html, eclipse

There are some HTML files in the Assets folder of my project which contain the error : `Self-closing syntax (/>) used on a non-void HTML element`

I can't compile my project due to these errors.

I don't know what's the problem here so i'm listing everything that could be relevant to the error.

- i recently switched to a Mac (from a PC).
- Installed the latest ADK & ADT Plugin on Eclipse JUNO.
- The same code worked fine on my last machine (Linux, also tried on Windows).
- I researched a bit and found that self closing tags are not allowed in HTML5, but were fine in HTML4.
- I'm guessing, there is some configuration which lets me switch to HTML4 parsing of my html files, which i was unable to find.
- I searched and couldn't find how to disable HTML validation. (There is no option for Validation, i.e.  `Preferences->Validation`)

Has someone faced this error before? Any solutions to this weird problem?

Note : there are hundreds of HTML files, and all of them have the same error. Also the codebase is being shared by many people. So changing the HTML code is not a viable option.

Comment: You can define your document to be of a certain doctype by putting a `<!DOCTYPE html>` tag on the first line. You can explicitly set that to html 4 e.g. `<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">`.

I don't know if that helps but it's worth a try.

Comment: I checked. Doesn't help.